play -pac4j oidc password grant send redirect url to torken end point
implementing play-pac4j oidc feature with keyclock.
I need it to support only for direct access grant but play-pac4j  request sends redirect_url as request parameter and getting error
< Invalid parameter: redirect_uri> from keyclock.
    final OidcConfiguration oidcConfiguration = new OidcConfiguration();
    oidcConfiguration.setDiscoveryURI(configuration.getString("oidc.discoveryUri"));
    oidcConfiguration.setClientId(configuration.getString("oidc.clientId"));
    //oidcConfiguration.setSecret(configuration.getString("oidc.clientSecret"));
    oidcConfiguration.setClientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC);
    oidcConfiguration.setExpireSessionWithToken(true);
    oidcConfiguration.setLogoutUrl("/logout");

    oidcConfiguration.setDisablePkce(true);

            
    final OidcClient oidcClient = new OidcClient(oidcConfiguration);
    oidcClient.addAuthorizationGenerator((CallContext ctx, UserProfile profile) -> {
        profile.addRole("ROLE_ADMIN");

        return Optional.of(profile);
    });

how to fix this code

What do you mean by "direct access grant"? The OidcClient is meant to perform a round-trip from the webapp to the identity provider.

pac4j-oidc support indirect client flows. I'm looking for For direct client flow implementation with pac4j

You may use the DirectBearerAuthClient for that: https://www.pac4j.org/docs/clients/openid-connect.html#b-direct-clients

yes now I figure it out , problem is now how to pass user credentials

With the DirectBearerAuthClient, credentials should be passed as a HTTP header named "Authorization", starting with "Bearer " then "login:pwd" are base64 encoded.
